# Luigi Central Scheduler Not Starting

Tags: python, etl, luigi

I have luigi running on two Windows 10 machines, on one of them the central scheduler is not rendering at port 8082.

First code from the machine that's not working:

```
C:\Users\shanlodh\luigitutorial>set PYTHONPATH=%cd%

C:\Users\shanlodh\luigitutorial>luigid
2021-02-21 12:05:05,214 luigi[15012] INFO: logging configured by default settings
2021-02-21 12:05:05,214 luigi.scheduler[15012] INFO: No prior state file exists at /var/lib/luigi-server/state.pickle. Starting with empty state
```

There's an additional line of output from the machine that **is** working on the `luigid` command, viz:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,%f, luigi.server[PID] INFO:Scheduler starting up
```

How can I get this last bit working on the first machine, thanks